# how to remove cookies from my website

Tags: asp.net, cookies, web-config

I developed a website with Asp.net Website project, and recently I added some https protocol on it. my problem is that the website shows that it is saving cookies, while I really do not like to save any cookies from my users. 
I am not familiar with cookies very much but I am sure I did not put any code to save user cookies, how I can be sure If there would not be any cookies for my users and delete any settings for this and why this happening automatically?

my project is a very simple single page website with no form and authentication

[image]

[image]

here is my web.config if needed.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>


 <configuration>



  <system.web>

  <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>


  <customErrors mode="On" />
  <sessionState mode="Off" /> 
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>



  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
    <clear />
     <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>

    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\(compressionType)\(AppPool)\(WebSite)\compressed files">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
   <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
  </httpCompression>



  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>




  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Appreciate very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net has by default session state (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) turned on, which in turn relies on cookies by default. If you don't need session state (because users don't logon etc) you can turn it off in the web.config file. Just add

```
<sessionState mode="Off">
```

under the

```
<system.web>
```

element.

Comment: would you please give the code which I should put on my web.config?

Comment: ok it seems it works fine, I add this on my web.config into system.web tag. now the problem is that it still hast two cookies on local storage and session storage. should I do something for these two? thank you really very much for your help

Comment: Can you specifiy the name of the cookies?

Comment: yes it shows that it still has two cookies one in local storage for example if my website is in MYRUL it shows   https ://myURL.com and the other one in session storage https ://myURL.com do you need a screenshot?

Comment: A screenshot would be nice yeah.

Comment: You didn't censor the URL in the screenshot so I could have a look on the site. Its comming from the McAfee plugin you run on your site.

Comment: I removed McAfee but still cookies there, Appreciate very much if you recheck and help me

Comment: If I check now I see only Google Analytics cookies. You can check if there is something in the local storage by going tot the Developer Tools (f12) and check storage under the tab Application.

Comment: ok thats fine thank you very very much. just last question, would these cookies matters users rights? should I ask my users for cookie permission ? if you know any information I really thank you to give me some

Comment: Since they are tracking/analytics cookies by Google I guess cookie permission is needed. But that depend on a lot of thing (local law etc). Can't give you a answer on that.

Comment: ok thank you very much, I got it . and also  I checked developer tools and there is something just in cookies table which if I want to tell you the truth I do not know what exactly are these things, how I should be sure its for google analytics? and it is my last question. thank you very much again